# cannot import name 'login_required' from 'helpers'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a web application using Flask where I'd like to use `login_required`. I'm a beginner and have been referring some already done codes and understood that `helpers` module has the function I require.

I tried installing helpers using `pip3 install helpers`

Now when I run my application I get this below error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'login_required' from 'helpers' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/helpers/__init__.py)
```

There could be other ways of handling the login's and sessions. But I'm curious to know why this error occurs for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`login_required` seems to be a function of the `Flask-Login` extension.

Also see

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In order to learn more about Flask I recommend the "Mega-Tutoral" by Miguel Grindberg, especially the chapter about login

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins

As a hint - your question suggests that you are just starting to program in Python. I would recommend to start the above mentioned tutorial from the beginning, or even start with a general Python tutorial, as from https://realpython.com/

Comment: Thanks J.G. I've started learning Python and taking small projects. I guess I've crossed the basics.

Anyway coming to my question. I know `Flask-Login` has `login_required` but there are codes I could see online that imports this from `helpers`.

Just curious to know if really `helpers` has this function.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would be super nice if you give my answer a "arrow up" and mark it as "correct answer". Thanks!

Comment: `helpers` is just a arbitrary name. It could be anything. It can be a module like `helpers.py` or a package, ie a folder. It could contain anything.

Comment: Done. Thanks. I used `dir(helpers)` to check to check if the `login_required` is a function under this module. And seems like it's not. Now I'll have to find an alternate for this.